# Is there a tool that can let me visualise timestamps by day/week/month?

Tags: linux, charts, timestamp, r

On our website we record thousands of events in tables each with a unique timestamp. Is there a tool that can plot for me the number of timestamps that fall within a day, week, or month, on a graph a-la-google analytics, to help me understand the trends?

Comment: What tables are we talking about here?  MySQL? PGSql? Sqlite? logarithm tables? dining tables?

Comment: or are we talking about events that goes into the log files?

Comment: In this case, stored in MySQL tables, but they essentially resemble log files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple graphing tool, take a look at [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/).

If you on the other hand want do do complex analysis, you would best use some sort of OLAP tool. I personally know [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) a little bit, which is an open source business analytics tool.

With Pentaho, you could use the [Kettle/Spool](http://kettle.pentaho.com/) ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) tool to aggregate your data. Using the [Mondrian Schema Designer](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/workbench.php) you could then describe your data structure to Pentaho.

Finally, within the Pentaho dashboard you'll find the Marketplace, where you can install open source tools to create dashboards or create dynamic queries via the [Saiku-UI](https://github.com/OSBI/saiku-ui)

I realize this is not your click-and-go solution, but in the long run you will get a lot more value out of this solution than a simple graphing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is already stored in a SQL database, you might look at SQL Reporting Services. It's not difficult to get it up and running, though a little coding knowledge will go a long way here.

This article gives an example very similar to your dataset:
http://rduclos.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/ssrs-2008-generate-calendars-based-on-a-date-range/